# Distributing a large file to N VMs with AzCopy

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azcopy

**CONTEXT**

My goal is to refresh 20 dev environments with fresh databases, and do it as quickly and reliably as possible. We generate a BAK, throw it into file storage, and then attempt (poorly) to bring it down to all of the boxes before I remotely trigger the unmount old / mount new on all boxes.

**ATTEMPT**

Right now I have the following as a Powershell Workflow:

```
Write-Output "Beginning workflow."
foreach -parallel ($dir in $destinations)
{
    $targetFile = "$dir\$sourcePattern"
    Write-Output "Checking: $targetFile"
    InlineScript{
        $fileExists = Test-Path $Using:targetFile
        if ($fileExists -eq $false){
            Write-Output "Copying to: $using:targetFile"
            &"$Using:AzCopyPath" /Source:"$Using:sourceDirectory" /Dest:$Using:dir /SourceKey:$Using:sourceKey /Pattern:"$Using:sourcePattern" /Z:$journalPath
            Write-Output "Copied to: " $Using:targetFile
        } else{
            Write-Output "Already copied: " $Using:targetFile
        }
```

This works beautifully for small text files, but for ~400GB database backups, it's not working so swell because the host machine gets totally overwhelmed.

What's the most sensible way to use AZCopy to copy a big file down to ~20 machines in an automated and parallelized fashion?

Comment: That's not a great architecture.  According to your narrative you'd be pushing ~8TB of data.  You need to consider other options - like torrent, or uploading to an Azure storage account.

Comment: Are the targets Azure VMs?  Have you thought about using Azure files and just mapping shares?

Comment: @SamAxe the file is in an azure storage account.

Comment: @CtrlDot - The Azure file storage drive is mapped on all machines - but we'll be restoring a compressed >1TB database, so I'm thinking the restoration is best done without any network latency involved.  Would you agree?

Comment: Yeah sure.  I guess I don't understand the full use case. Could you deploy the sql database on one box, then clone it 19 times?

Comment: @CtrlDot - I could - this is my effort at parallelizing the task. My goal is to refresh 20 dev environments with fresh databases, and do it as quickly and reliably as possible.  We generate a BAK, throw it into file storage, and then attempt (poorly) to bring it down to all of the boxes as above.

Comment: Understood.  I would say if you are using ARM templating,  creating a base image with the latest database and then provisioning 20 copies (all parallel because you can do that in ARM) is the best/fastest way to go with the least amount of cost. Not really an answer to your question, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please elaborate "the host machine gets totally overwhelmed.". It is possible that you may be hitting scale limits on Azure File Share or other limits on Storage accounts. Target throughput for single file share is up to 60 MB/sec so please make sure you are not exceeding that limit. If you are hitting that limit, you may want to consider putting the contents in multiple File shares. See performance scale limits for Files and Storage accounts in the following MSDN article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/. Please also check to make sure your storage account and Azure VMs are in the same region to reduce the network latency.

Thanks,
Aung